# React state data not ready after redirect

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I built a login/register system with react and node.

After i login I call a loadUser method which loads the user. This works perfectly fine. But as soon as I redirect after loging in the data in the state is not available to me. Without redirect it works fine. And the user loads and shows in my state. But after a redirect nothing appears.

login component :

```
const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    login({email,password});
};

if(isAuthenticated && !isLoading){
    return  <Redirect to="/dashboard"/>
 }
```

login action :

```
export const login = ({email,password}) => async dispatch => {
    const config = {
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        }
    };

    const body = JSON.stringify({email,password});

    try {
        const res = await axios.post('/auth', body, config);
        dispatch({type : LOGIN_SUCCESS , payload:res.data});
        dispatch(loadUser());
    } catch(err){
        const errors = err.response.data.errors;

        if(errors) {
            errors.forEach(error => {
                dispatch(setAlert(error.msg,'error'));
            })
        }
        dispatch({type: LOGIN_FAIL});
    }

};
```

the page i redirect to :

import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

```
const Dashboard = ({user}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{user.name}</h1>
        </div>
    )
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {user : state.auth.user};
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Dashboard);
```

As you can see in the login action the loadUser method is run. Why is user : null when i redirect to dashboard. But without redirecting it's fine..

EDIT:

```
import {
    REGISTER_SUCCESS,
    REGISTER_FAIL,
    LOAD_USER,
    AUTH_ERROR,
    LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    LOGIN_FAIL,
} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    token : localStorage.getItem('token'),
    isAuthenticated : null,
    loading: true,
    user : null,
};

export default function(state = initialState , action) {
    const {payload, type} = action;

    switch (type) {
        case LOAD_USER:
            return {
                ...state, 
                isAuthenticated : true,
                loading: false,
                user: payload
            }; 

        case REGISTER_SUCCESS:
        case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            console.log(payload.token)
            localStorage.setItem('token', payload.token);
            return {
                ...state,
                ...payload,
                isAuthenticated: true,
                loading:false
            };

        case REGISTER_FAIL:
        case AUTH_ERROR:   
        case LOGIN_FAIL:  
            localStorage.removeItem('token');
            return {
                ...state,
                token: null,
                isAuthenticated:null,
                loading:false
            };

        default:
            return state;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add your reducer ?

Comment: @ocheriaf I added the reducer

Comment: you are using redirect is like refreshing page please check here  https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect

Comment: And furthermore, when you call the loadUser action, you don't send any payload, so the reducer delete the user property in the state as it returns a state with a user equals to payload which is undefined

Answer (score 0):

So the user in the state is not directly available so i had to build in a check.

```
const Dashboard = ({user}) => {
    return (<div>
        <h1>{user ? (<div>{user.name}</div>) : (<div>loading...</div>)}</h1>
    </div>)

};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {user : state.auth.user};
};
```

What this does is it shows a loading message for a fe mili seconds and then it gives me my user data.